# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol clock()

Tags: c, compilation, linker, linker-errors

I have added #include  in component.c file and created variables with  clock_t type and clock(), which is compiling successfully.

```
clock_t start_t, end_t, total_t;
start_t = clock();
```

When i build the driver file(.sys) there is a linker which tries to find clock() but it cannot find and throws error.

component.lib(comp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol clock
driver.sys : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I have tried reading other solutions for similar linker error.
Most of them has mentioned about Microsoft visual c++ compiler.

```
clock_t start_t, end_t, total_t;
start_t = clock();
```

I have tried adding extern in the component.c file. But it doesn't help.

```
extern clock(void);
```